# Extraer Datos de una Web con Javascript con <IFRAME> u <OBJECT> HTML

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Hola tengo un problema he intentado acceder a datos de una web que no es mía, WEB PARA CONSULTAR CÉDULAS O ID DE IDENTIFICACIÓN

Lo intente desde un con funciones de javascript a intentar extraer el contenido de un resultado de la web dentro del iframe. Tienen algún ejemplo?

```js
function  extraercedula(){

 
  var x=document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow.MainContent_Cedula.value;
  //MainContent_Cedula es el id de input dentro del IFRAME
  //CEDULA es el id del input donde quiero pegar el contenido extraido
              document.getElementById("CEDULA").value=x;




}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
  iframe {
    width: 767px;
    height: 500px;
  }
</style>
<body>
  <iframe src="https://www.corporacionregistrocivil.gob.ec/Formularios/CeduladosGratuita?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1" id="frame" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  <input type="text" id="CEDULA">
  <input type="button" value="Extraer" onclick="extraercedula();">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Esa web debe de retornar alguna respuesta ya sea de acuerdo a POST o GET, intenta lo siguiente, busca directamente en la web (tal cuál lo harías normalmente), es decir que pones tu cedula y demas, si al momento de dar click, la pagina no se recarga si no que se añade contenido arriba de la URL significa que el metodo usado es GET, de lo contrario es POST, si el metodo es GET, puedes usar una URL especial que te devuelva esos datos haciendo esa petición con por ejemplo ajax o de manera normal, si el metodo es POST, entonces es mas complejo.

Comment: si, pero el fin no es extraer la cedula si no los datos,Nombre y Apellidos

Comment: La petición puede que te de estos datos también.

Comment: Intentare extraer el codigo fuente después de la consulta y analizado el resultado

Comment: No necesitas extraer el código fuente entero, solo hacer una consulta por medio de tu formulario a esa url. Te debe dar algunos datos importantes y no la pagina entera.

Answer (score 1):

Me funcionó con `innerHTML`. Sería así:

```
document.getElementById("CEDULA").innerHTML=x;
```

Comment: Esa url del iframe no es accesible desde según que lugares, no se puede verificar tu respuesta (al menos yo), por lo tanto no se de donde sacas lo de `followers`... el que pregunta decia **CEDULA** y no _followers_.

Comment: Me he confundido es CEDULA, porque en mi proyecto era followers. A mí me funcionó el iframe cambiando solo la parte innerHTML

Comment: Cambialo en la respuesta pues, así será más acorde con la pregunta, es decir, puedes [editarla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/510269/edit) de nuevo y modificar ese dato

Comment: Muchas gracias!